# Strange Thing: getting error if using SQLOLEDB instead of ODBC in connection string

Tags: sql-server-2008, asp-classic, odbc, connection-string, oledb

**BACKGROUND:**

 
Our Classic ASP & SQL Server based application was working perfectly with ODBC connection string.

However, after a recent windows update, application went DOWN, application was giving error code: 8888FFFF (Catastrophic failure)

To solve that, our DBA did some research, and found that if we use OLEDB connection string application can be UP again.

Now, as we are using OLEDB connection string, **almost 98%** percent of the application is running FINE.

The **2% glitch** is being faced at places where basically inserts queries are used inside stored procedures.

**ISSUE:**

If I use OLEDB connection string  instead of ODBC connection string then I am getting ADODB.Recordset (0x800A0E78)  error. 
Operation is not allowed when the object is closed.

**OLEDB connection string:**

```
strConnectionString = "Provider=sqloledb;Data Source=path\MyDBServer;database=MyDB;uid=xxx;pwd=xxx"
```

**ODBC connection string:**

```
strConnectionString = "driver={SQL Server};server=path\MyDBServer;database=MyDB;uid=xxx;pwd=xxx"
```

**What I have tried:** 
1. Using 'Provider=SQLNCLI10;' instead of 'Provider=sqloledb;' in connection string.

I have got a [work Around from stack exchange](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18127018/asp-stored-procedure-operation-is-not-allowed-when-the-object-is-closed):

```
If rsRecordSet.State <> 1 Then 
While rsRecordSet.State <> 1
Set rsRecordSet = rsRecordSet.NextRecordset
Wend
End If
```

Still if this could be solved from connection string then it would be great. Otherwise I need to apply work around solution at each and every place of error.

Thanks!

Comment: Possibly because you are using the wrong "OLEDB" string see [SQL Server Native Client 10.0 OLE DB Provider connection strings](http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server-native-client-10-0-oledb-provider/). Try `strConnectionString = "Provider=SQLNCLI10;Server=path\MyDBServer;Database=MyDB;Uid=xxx;Pwd=xxx"`

Comment: ConnectionStrings.com should be on every developer's bookmark list!

Comment: @Paul I'm not sure if that is what is causing their error though, it could just be the older OLEDB string causing compatibility issues with data types in [tag:SQL-Server-2008]. Or it could be something completely different.

Comment: We don't actually know what's throwing the exception: setting a variable to a string literal wouldn't cause it. We need to know how the OP is using the connection string.

Comment: @Lankymart: Setting Provider=SQLNCLI10 is not working.

Comment: @all: I am editing question with more details.

Comment: @jaczjill You can't just change the provider some of the other parameters are also different `Data Source` is `Database` for example look at the full example I posted.

Comment: @Lankymart: Still it doesn't work! I have verified all parameters as per your ConnectionString post.. also tried other SQL Server connection strings (SQL server 05\08)...

Comment: What is your `ADODB.Recordset` returning, what query or stored procedure are you passing? Need to see more of the code to give a definitive answer, just showing the returned `ADODB.Recordset` object isn't enough because are that point it's `.State` property is already set to `adStateClosed`.

Comment: Lol, technically that's not a workaround it's what you should be doing. When working with stored procedures (especially unfamiliar ones) it is advisable to check the `ADODB.Recordset` `.State` property to make sure the `ADODB.Recordset` is in a state where it can be interrogated.

Answer (score 2):

With OLEDB provider, the SQL-Server return the number of lines touched by each query in a closed recordset before the final resultset.  This recordset is used by the provider to detect some types of error and is closed to make sure that the user won't confuse it with the real, final resulset.

You can either look for the next recordset as you have already found or you can add the following instruction at the beginning of your SP or before your Select query (if you are using a query string) in order to eliminate the sending of the number of lines for each query:

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;
```

I prefer this last solution as it make the VBScript code simpler but it's just a matter of taste.

In your case, why the original ODBC provider doesn't work anymore, I have no idea but by looking at connectionstrings.com; you can try using a more recent ODBC provider.  However, pure OLEDB providers should give you a better performance with ADO than ODBC.

Comment: How many times we had this answer before?, didn't realise that `SET NOCOUNT ON;` was specific to OLEDB providers?

Comment: For what I remember, the problem with `SET NOCOUNT ON` was specific with the first versions of OLEDB providers when they make their entry many years ago.  I have no idea if this is still the case with the newer versions of ODBC providers as I never checked but it's possible.  I'll try to do it later.  However, in my case, everytimes I saw this particular problem with a closed recordset that come first, I've always be able to solve it by adding a `SET NOCOUNT ON` in my query.  I don't remember a single case where it would have failed.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's still an issue even with later providers *(SQL Server Management Studio even sets it in the Stored Procedure creation template by default)*. But you can also create closed recordsets based on the logic in your stored procedures. For example placing a `SELECT` inside a `IF` block means that the stored procedure might or might not return a resultset at which point the `ADODB.Recordset` will be returned with a `.State` property set to `adStateClosed`.

Comment: Yes, this is another possibility. However, if this was the case (a `Select` inside a `If` block), the above solution of checking for the next NextRecordset if the first one is closed would still be insufficient as you would still have to check for whatever remains at the end of the loop and return immediately if a Null recordset is returned by the NextRecordset; therefore the problem would still be open.

Comment: My comment on the question was purely about checking the `ADODB.Recordset` `.State` property before trying to interrogate the object. Don't agree with the `While` loop approach myself.

Comment: Both `.Execute()` and `.NextRecordset()` return a `ADODB.Recordset` but depending on what your Stored Procedure returns the states will be different so whenever you call either of these methods check the `.State` property.

Comment: Either way your answer deserves a +1

Comment: With the introduction of SQL-Server 7 and ADODB, they have added this option supposedly to give us a better error messaging mecanism but honestly, this is probably the "feature" with which I've lost the most of my time since then.  They should have set it a ON by default and a lot of people would have saved a lot of time (and would still save) over the years.